# JTable, JLabel, and its Icon (JLabel can't be customized with Icon)?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtable, jlabel

This summer is not a real summer, i thought.
A cup of coffee make me feel it as a summer, tough (lol).

I have a little bit naughty JTable. OMG.
Below is my JTable that use my own customized TableModel. You could see it on its method of **getColumnClass**(), there... it was made for returning as **JLabel** only.
ANd then, I also **customize** the **DefaultRenderer**.

```
jtbl_inGameEasy = new javax.swing.JTable();
jtbl_inGameEasy.setFont(new java.awt.Font("squeaky chalk sound", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
jtbl_inGameEasy.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
jtbl_inGameEasy.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {

    },
    new String [] {
        "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"
    }
) {
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
        false, false, false, false, false
    };

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit [columnIndex];
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return JLabel.class;
    }
});
jtbl_inGameEasy.setDefaultRenderer(JLabel.class, new JLabelTableRenderer());
jtbl_inGameEasy.setFocusable(false);
jtbl_inGameEasy.setOpaque(false);
jtbl_inGameEasy.setRowHeight(55);
jtbl_inGameEasy.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
jtbl_inGameEasy.setShowVerticalLines(false);
jtbl_inGameEasy.setTableHeader(null);
jtbl_inGameEasy.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jtbl_inGameEasyMousePressed(evt);
    }
});
```

And Where is the **JTableRenderer**? Here...
this is my Custom Renderer below...

```
public class JLabelTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (value instanceof JLabel) {
            //This time return only the JLabel without icon
            return (JLabel) value;
        } else {
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }

    }
}
```

And then, I need to pu JLabel inside each of the Cell. 
I start to **add** some JLabel(s) inside the Object of Array over the Cells of the **JTable** using this code; (which is no problem).

```
DefaultTableModel o_dtb = jtbl_inGameEasy.getModel();
o_dtb.addRow(myArrayCustomizedObjectofJLabel);
```

Everything works fine, I guess. But because of My purpose is that ---> To put an **Icon** or to make it Invisible once the **user Click** on JTable **Cells**, thus I I tried to do my **MouseEvent** once **pressed** and calling these lines of code;

```
private void jtbl_inGameEasyMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
        // Checking inGameEasy Table Ans
        javax.swing.JTable source = (javax.swing.JTable) evt.getSource();
        int row = source.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int column = source.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());

        DefaultTableModel o_dtb = (DefaultTableModel) jtbl_inGameEasy.getModel();
        String s_questAns = "" + Game.getCurrentQuestion().getResult();
        String s_userAns = "" + o_dtb.getValueAt(row, column);

// These two lines below are not Working, why yaa??    

    ((JLabel) o_dtb.getValueAt(row, column)).setVisible(false);
((JLabel) o_dtb.getValueAt(row, column)).setIcon(myIcon);

        if (s_questAns.equals(s_userAns)) {
            Game.correct();
            System.err.println("nice ans!");
        } else {
            jll_txtMiss.setText("Miss : " + Game.wrong());
            System.err.println("nope!");
        }

        nextQuestion();
    }
```

And seems to me that the **Marked** (below the **commented**) code above are not working. 
Yeah, the JLabel casted couldn't be changed its Icon (image), and nor its visibility as well. Is it the **Model cause all of this**? 
NB: My Cells data added later after the Model created differently.

Comment: Edit your essay...ohhhh sorry I meant question! Make it short and right on point. Thanks

Comment: I think you are massively overcomplicating this! By default a JTable uses a JLabel as the default renderer for most Object types. So you could have simply added an Icon to the individual Cell as part of the onClick event, reducing a ton of code.

Comment: just question, that should be TicTacToe, Minesweeper, Pexeso..., direction is good, don't worry about that, JTable but default contains JLabel in the TabelCell, accepted Icon.Class too, please time to create example, you should use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049494/how-to-get-icon-from-jtable/7051005#7051005 as basis for that, be sure that would same/similair is you'll crate Array of JLabels or put that to the JTable, just you have to look for register MouseEvent in the TableCell (lots of examples here)

Comment: JTable rendering its cells as JLabel ?? Is that true?? I thuoght they're more preferr to choose Object instead of JLabel.... @mKorbel :(      oya, thanks for the Link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that what you want to do is to just leave all table cells empty, except the ones clicked by the user, where some mark icon should appear, right?

If so, your table model should not contain `JLabel` instances. A JLabel is a visual component, used to render some data graphically. The data itself is not a JLabel. In your case, I think it should thus be a Boolean (true when clicked by the user, false otherwise).

Now you could use a custom renderer (although the default one for booleans could also be OK) to display your booleans. This renderer would be a subclass of `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, which is itself a subclass of JLabel. The renderer (the same instance for all the cells configured to use this renderer) would just display a *marked* icon if the Boolean value to render is true, and a *not marked* icon (or no icon at all) when the Boolean value to render is false.

Then, your click handler would just have one mission: make the clicked cell contain true rather than false. To do that, it would just have to change the appropriate value in the table model.

To recap: a table model is used to hold data. Think of it as the data you would find in a database. Would you hold a JLabel in the database? No, you would hold a boolean, a string or an integer. The table can render this data as you want, and this is the mission of the renderer.

Side note: stop with the hungarian notation: it doesn't make sense in Java. It makes code hard to read. Everything except primitive types is an object, and you can't assign a meaningful prefix to every possible type. Rather, use readable and meaningful english names : `tableModel` rather than `o_dtb`, `correctAnswer` rather than `s_questAns`, `userAnswer` rather than `s_userAns`.

Comment: +1 Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833482/how-to-represent-double-values-as-circles-in-a-2d-matrix-in-java/2834484#2834484) that `extends DefaultTableCellRenderer` and `implements Icon`.

Comment: my grandma born in the Hungary, :-) are you some problem with that, or want to with me :-), reason of my comment == excelent descriptions +1

Comment: omg.... so that's the Hungarian Notation you guys talked about! (lol) okay, okay, I have hundreds of those Hungarian Variables in my Netbeans ( i guess ). :D