# Ho do I display results from a db query in a scroll pane with an array of checkboxes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, checkbox

In java I query a db and retrieve a result set, which I want to display in a scrolling pane.

Along with displaying the the results of the query, I want to have a checkbox on the left side of each row in the scrolling pane.

Adding the checkboxes is the part that I don't know how to do. Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Swing and my IDE is Netbeans 7.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Stan's example, the [default renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for `Boolean` is a `JCheckbox`, so return `Boolean` for the column's class. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).

Comment: You may want to open a new question. See also [*Table From Database*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/).

Comment: Thanks for the example. I modified your example in the link above to create a table using a ResultSet from a MySQL table. It works beautifully, for the most part. There are a couple questions I have, though. Most pressing is that when I sort columns composed of strings the sort works just fine, but when I try to sort columns of type: java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, Boolean, or Double I get an error. (Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String). Also, is there a way to make cells not editable by the user?

Comment: You can return `false` from `isCellEditable()`.

Comment: to make all of the cells in the table not editable, I used the following code: 'JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
    return false;               
    };
};'

Comment: No, override `isCellEditable()` in the `TableModel`, not the view.

Comment: Thanks...I am now overriding the TableModel

Comment: Just for the record, I had to be [reminded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9155689/230513) of this myself, not once but _twice_! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use JTable palcing it into a JScrollPane
The link how to convert ResultSet to TableModel
http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/59-resultset-to-tablemodel