# Add Image in JTable without using renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I need to add image in Jtable cell without using TableCellRenderer.If i Use  the following code means it display the name (string) in that particular cell instead of image.how to do this?.

```
 ImageIcon Icon= new ImageIcon("Blank.gif");
 table.setValueAt(Icon,1,0);


using renderer

class FRM_FLXD_ICON_ASSGN extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
       ImageIcon Icon;
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
      JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focus,
      int row, int col) {
       if(selected == true){
           Icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pointer.gif"));
       }
   else{
            Icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Blank.gif"));
     }
       this.setIcon(Icon);
       return this;
     }

}
```

Comment: welcome to the forum :-) While you are at learning, please learn java naming conventions as well and stick to them

Comment: *"without using renderer"*  ***Why?***

Comment: @AndrewThompson if i use renderer means i create separate class,so that.

Comment: So what?  What is the problem?  If code creates another class, or causes it to be created (by default, or by using another class), it is a trifling thing.  If code creates so many extra objects that it throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, that is a problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson class FRM_FLXD_ICON_ASSGN extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
       ImageIcon Icon;
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
      JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focus,
      int row, int col) {
       if(selected == true){
           Icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pointer.gif"));
       }
   else{
            Icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Blank.gif"));
     }
       this.setIcon(Icon);
       return this;
     }

} if i use this, the blank image set whole table column.just i click one column it will display pointer.gif

Comment: @AndrewThompson how to change ,if i select one row the pointer.gif will display in that particular cell.then i click another row the pointer.gif will show in that place. the previous select cell will display Blank.gif.How to prevent to set blank.gif in all cell of column(0)

Comment: I cannot read code in comments.  Please edit it into your question, select the code and click the `{}` button above the message editing form.

Comment: @Andrew I added renderer code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) know [Icon/ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) Object, then you can add `Icon/ImageIcon` directly to the `JTable`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051005/714968)

Comment: what are the changes needed in the above coding for display the image?

Comment: just downvoted your example (how could I possibly have missed that :-)

Comment: Nice example, but what is with the `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
            }
        });`?  (Empty runnable)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson :-) maaaaay beee I removed some code, maaaybe nothing, who's know what rice I smoked on this day, I have to .... thanks !!!