# How to paint an image in Jtable with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Hello I would like to print data from  mysql query to my Jtable, I knw how to print the conventional data(String), but do not know how to do it with pictures. What I need is print the picture in the first cell of the table.

```
 public void SearchMovie() throws SQLException {

        try {
            Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Statement st = null;

            String Genre = ComboGenero.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String Era = ComboEra.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String Clsssification = ComboClasification.getSelectedItem().toString();

            String sql = "select Foto,Title,Year,Country ,Rating from movie where Genre ='" + Genre + "'";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/whichmovie", "Asis", "dekrayat24");


            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            this.jTable1.setModel(model);
            jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new IconCellRenderer());

             jTable1.setRowHeight(40);
            ResultSetMetaData rsMD = rs.getMetaData();
            int numcolumnas = rsMD.getColumnCount();

            for (int x = 1; x <= numcolumnas; x++) {
                model.addColumn(rsMD.getColumnLabel(x));

            }

            while (rs.next()) {

                Object[] fila = new Object[numcolumnas];
                for (int i = 0; i < numcolumnas; i++) {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                    ResultadosLabel.setText(numcolumnas + "Movies found");

                }
                model.addRow(fila);

            }



            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

Thanks .

Comment: if you add `System.out.println(fila[0].getClass())` what is printed?

Comment: before `rs.close()` I suppose

Comment: I found the solution [here][1] similar to your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527477/different-imageicon-in-different-cells-in-jtable

Comment: durron597 .it prints class[B

Comment: Tin .i need somthing like that but getting images from mysql