# How to add text next to image in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon

I have a three column jtable and want to have the first two columns have an Imageicon and a string right next to it.

Currently I am displaying the ImageIcons like

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
                            @Override
                            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                                switch (column) {
                                    case 0:
                                    case 1:
                                        return ImageIcon.class;
                                    case 2:
                                        return String.class;
                                    default:
                                        return Object.class;
                                }
                            }
                        };

jTable.setModel(model);
```

I did find this but don't know what goes in `...` or how to set the ImageIcon and string in the jtable with this:

[Java - Is it possible to put an image and a String in the same JTable cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208884/java-is-it-possible-to-put-an-image-and-a-string-in-the-same-jtable-cell)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did find this but don't know what goes in ... or how to set the ImageIcon and string in the jtable with this:

You need to create custom Object (lets say you call it MyCustomObject) to hold the information you want to display. So your custom Object will have two properties: Icon and Text.

Then you create the Object and add to the TableModel like you do for any other Object in the table.

You need to override the getColumnClass() method to return `MyCustomObject` for the first two columns. Then you also need to set the custom renderer for the `MyCustomObject`.

So then in the rendering code you would do something like:

```
MyCustomObject data = (MyCustomObject)value;
setIcon(data.getIcon());
setText(data.getText());
```

Answer (score 3):

Because [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) is `JLabel`, you can use it's text alignment properties in a custom [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to label the icon. The example below overrides `getRowHeight()` to ensure visibility. I've [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36830558/revisions) the example to use a custom class, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36828624/230513); an instance of `LabelIcon` holds an icon and label pair for each row.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830558/230513
 */
public class TableExample {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Demo");
    private Icon errorIcon = (Icon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = (Icon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = (Icon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Icon"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"One", new LabelIcon(errorIcon, "Error")},
        {"Two", new LabelIcon(infoIcon, "Information")},
        {"Three", new LabelIcon(warnIcon, "Warning")},
        {"Four", new LabelIcon(errorIcon, "Error")},
        {"Five", new LabelIcon(infoIcon, "Information")},
        {"Six", new LabelIcon(warnIcon, "Warning")}};
    private final TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return LabelIcon.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }
    };

    private static class LabelIcon {

        Icon icon;
        String label;

        public LabelIcon(Icon icon, String label) {
            this.icon = icon;
            this.label = label;
        }
    }

    private static class LabelIconRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public LabelIconRenderer() {
            setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object
            value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            JLabel r = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            setIcon(((LabelIcon) value).icon);
            setText(((LabelIcon) value).label);
            return r;
        }
    }

    public TableExample() {
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public int getRowHeight() {
                return super.getRowHeight() + infoIcon.getIconHeight();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(
                    (5 * super.getPreferredSize().width) / 4,
                    4 * this.getRowHeight());
            }
        };
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(LabelIcon.class, new LabelIconRenderer());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            TableExample tableExample = new TableExample();
        });
    }
}
```