# Displaying an alternative text when meet wrong location

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am working for Swing accessibility. I am using `ImageIcon`. I need to place the alternative textual information when image URL is broken.

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on how to write questions. For starters: 1. Please format your code. 2. Add more code to your question to help us understand it better and for future readers to benefit from this question. 3. Look for other questions which might help you out already. 4. Format your text, and give us a minimum working example

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, all supported Swing [Look & Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) implementations include an `Icon` named `"html.missingImage"`:

```
Icon missing = UIManager.getIcon("html.missingImage");
```

A `ListCellRenderer` using the icon is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19092305/230513); a related `TableCellRenderer` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830558/230513). Note that each uses `setHorizontalTextPosition()` and `setVerticalTextPosition()` to position the label's text relative to the icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem so the answer is :
Just surround you code with try and catch

```
ImageIcon icon = null;
try {
  icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("yourimageUrlHere"));
} catch(Exception e) {
  icon = new ImageIcon("your placeholder path");
}
```